# On click of check box i am trying to display some text onpage (Using lighting componets for same)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-id

I am trying to display some text on Page by using  Lighting componets.i am not getting that  text on click on check box
Below is my code .Let mek nwo where is my code wrong.

A>Component
attribute define

```
<aura:attribute name="CheckBoxValue" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
```

Lightning tag with aura id defined in it

```
<lightning:input aura:id="checkBoxAM" label="Are you new to this course" name="HaveYouTakenCourseBefore" type="checkbox" onchange="{!c.onClickCheckBox}"/>
```

B>This is my Aura if  conditiontag along with text to be displayed

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.CheckBoxValue}">
        <br/>
            Hello  You have checked this box
 </aura:if>
```

C>THis is my JS function in Controller

```
onClickCheckBox: function(component,event,helper) {

    // accesing the value of attribute HaveYouTakenCourseBefore;
    // Call function defined in helper;
    // hlpr.<Function Name in helper>
    console.log("This text is from helper function");
    helper.onClickCheckBoxhelper(component);

        }
```

D>This is my FUnction defined in helper

```
onClickCheckBoxhelper : function(component) {

        //body of helper resourse
        // define logic of your function
        console.log("This text is from helper function");
        var checkBoxValue = component.find("checkBoxAM").get("v.checked");
        component.set("v.checkBoxAM",checkBoxValue);
```

E> Calling this Component in my Lightning App

PFA screen shot
[image]

Comment: What did you do to my question ? What is edited  not getting

Answer (score 0):

Hi I see that the attribute you're validating on the IF is **CheckBoxValue** but the one your seeting on your helper method is **checkBoxAM**.

My recomendation would be to modify the helper method to this:

component.set("v.CheckBoxValue",checkBoxValue);

Comment: No is nt working by changing that